# How to restart worker for a topology programatically in Apache Storm

Tags: java, apache-storm

I am facing an issue in Apache Storm

**Problem Scenario**:

1. When Small data is sent to Storm, data gets processed properly by topology (has only 1 worker thread) and give further away to persist in MongoDB.
2. But when data is huge, it processes data and persist in DB but will not accept any other data afterwards whether the data is big or small.

**Current Workaround**:

we restart worker from Storm UI.

**Question**:

Can we restart topology worker programatically?

Answer (score 0):

Storm has two bolt types: IRichBolt and IBasicBolt. If you  implement IBasicBolt you should implement Acknowledge too. Also you should send Ack in your bolt to prevent locking.These links are good:

http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.6/Concepts.html
http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.2.2/Guaranteeing-message-processing.html

Comment: Can you elaborate it in bit detail? or can you provide link that explains it?

Answer (score 0):

It's never a good solution to restart the workers, you may lose some tuples. The best practice would be to exploit Storm message reliability functionality, as answered by Rahim.

However, other than message reliability storm has an inner backpressure mechanism, this means that when the Spouts injects more data than what the Bolts are able to process, the Spout will automatically slow down.

To enable this you need first, as said by Rahim, to enable acking. This means if your topology is a simple:

Spout -> Bolt

The spout will do:

```
public void nextTuple(){
  ...
  _collector.emit(new Values(tuple), tupleId);
}

@Override
publci void ack(Object msgId) { super.ack(msgId); }
```

Where the tupleId an simply be an incremental counter `count++`. In this way you declare to Storm the new tuple waiting to be acked.

Meanwhile in the successive bolt, and all the successive bolts in the topology, or at least until the one that cause your bottleneck, you will write:

```
public void execute(Tuple tuple){
  ...
  _collector.emit(tuple, new Values(newTuple));
  _collector.ack(tuple);
}
```

In this way you'll notice Storm that the tuple has been fully processed.

Least but not last, in your main method, where you declare the topology builder, you have to define the maximum number of tuples that the Spout will wait:

```
Config conf = new Config();
conf.setMaxSpoutPending(100);
```

In this way the Spout will start to produce new tuples waiting them to be acked, if (in this case) the number of pending tuples exceed 100 the spout will stop calling the method nextTuple, waiting them to be acked and then generating the new ones.

N.B.: the value 100 is just an example, you may have to tune it up a little bit to optimaze it to your situation.

The links shared by Rahim should be enough to understand the mechanism, anyway if you want to deep down to the implementation I add this link:

- http://storm.apache.org/releases/current/Acking-framework-implementation.html